# How to pass a multiple array into fpdf [CodeIgniter]?

Tags: codeigniter, controller, fpdf

So this is my controller :

```
public function Print1($Gen,$Class) {        
    $data['Payment'] = $this->print_model->select_data_payment();
    $data['Class'] = $this->print_model->select_data_class($Gen,$Class);
    $this->load->view('print/Print_Recap1',$data);
}
```

I want to pass multiple array into fpdf but i got errors such as :

- Undefined variable
- Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file

does anyone know how to fix it ?

thank you in advance for the help

Comment: And where is fpdf code?

Comment: you should post your fpdf code

Comment: you should provide your Print_Recap1 code